# Copy values from column and transpose into next blank row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy values from an specific column and then paste them in transpose in the first the columns, so, If a enter 3 values vertically, paste them horizontaly into the next available row.

[image: Example]

I've used the appendRow function but paste the vales under the source values in not after the destination header.

**After use this code, I get this:**, but doesn't paste the values after first row (header)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qzcR.png)

```
function transpose(sh) {
  var arrayThisRow,cellValue,i,j,lastCol,lastrow,numrows,pastesheet,
      rowrange,rowValues,sh;

  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
  pastesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");

  lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
  lastCol = sh.getLastColumn();
  Logger.log('lastCol: ' + lastCol);

  numrows = lastrow;
  arrayThisRow = [];

  for(i=1; i<= numrows; i++) {
    //Logger.log(i);
    rowrange = sh.getRange(i,4,2,lastCol);
    //Logger.log(rowrange);

    rowValues = rowrange.getValues();//
    rowValues = rowValues[1];//There is only 1 inner array

    for(j=0; j <= lastCol; j++) {

      cellValue = rowValues[j];

      if (cellValue) {
        arrayThisRow.push(cellValue);
      } else {
        break;//Stop pushing values into the array as soon as a blank cell is found
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log('arrayThisRow: ' + arrayThisRow)
  if (arrayThisRow.length > 0) {
    pastesheet.appendRow(arrayThisRow)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you wish to accomplish here.

If more than three values are input in your example, would you want the 4th, 5th and 6th values to be on a second row? In other words, are you looking to paste specifically 3 values per row?

Edit:

This function should do the trick. It isn't the prettiest of code, but should get the job done. There's plenty of other ways to create the object, but this was how it came naturally to me as I wrote it :)

```
function myFunction() {
  //Get values of all nonEmpty cells
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getRange("D:D").getValues().filter(String);

  //Create object with 3 columns max
  var pasteValues = [];
  var row = ["","",""];
  for (i = 1; i<values.length+1; i++){
    row.splice((i%3)-1,1,values[i-1]);
    if(i%3 == 0){
      pasteValues.push(row);
      var row = ["","",""]
    }
  }
  if(row != []){
    pasteValues.push(row)
  }

  //Paste the object in columns A to C
  ss.getRange(1,1,pasteValues.length,pasteValues[0].length).setValues(pasteValues);

}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, paste any entered value in the Column D and paste them in the first blank row. Due the example, I'll only enter 3 values, that need to be pasted in the 3 columns

Comment: Hi David,
I think I created a solution for you. Have a look and let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, worked but only after run the first time, If I want to add another row with data, it doesn't paste them. Seems like overwrite the previous pasted values

Comment: Hi David,
Can you specify what you mean by 'another row of data'. Does this mean that you are adding more numbers in Column D or are you adding numbers in a new column?

Comment: Yes, If I enter 1,2,3 in column D vertically, paste these values horizontally for each column separated.

Comment: Hi David,
I'm not entirely sure I understand how you want the sheet to work. Can I ask you to share a dummy sheet? Sorry about this!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my usecase is a little more involved maybe if you can chime in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397200/google-appscript-transpose-dynamic-data-group-from-one-column it would help others and myself