# Google Appscript transpose dynamic data group from one column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been jogging my brain trying to figure out how to write this script to transpose data from one sheet to another from a pretty dirty sheet.

There are other questions like this but none seem to be like my particular use case.

This is how the sheet is currently structured (somewhat):

[image]

The biggest issue here is I have no concrete idea how many rows a particular group of data will be, But **I know** there are always a bunch of blank rows between each group of data.

I found [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280674/copy-values-from-column-and-transpose-into-next-blank-row) that took me half way:

```
function myFunction() {
  //Get values of all nonEmpty cells
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getRange("D:D").getValues().filter(String);

  //Create object with 3 columns max
  var pasteValues = [];
  var row = ["","",""];
  for (i = 1; i<values.length+1; i++){
    row.splice((i%3)-1,1,values[i-1]);
    if(i%3 == 0){
      pasteValues.push(row);
      var row = ["","",""]
    }
  }
  if(row != []){
    pasteValues.push(row)
  }

  //Paste the object in columns A to C
  ss.getRange(1,1,pasteValues.length,pasteValues[0].length).setValues(pasteValues);

}
```

But in that case the asker dataset was fixed. I can loosely say that the max number of rows each group would have is 10(this is an assumption after browsing 3000 rows of the sheet...but if the script can know this automatically then it would be more dynamic). So with that in mind...and after butchering the script...I came up with this...which in no way works how it should currently(not all the data is being copied):

```
function myFunction() {
 
  var copyfrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('copyfrom')
  var copyto = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('copyto')
  
  var values = copyfrom.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(Array);

  var pasteValues = [];

  var row = [];

  for (i = 1; i<values.length; i++){

       if(values[i] != ""){
       row.push(values[i])
       }
     
      Logger.log(row);

      if(i%10 == 0){
      pasteValues.push(row);
      row = []
    }

  }

  if(row != []){
    pasteValues.push(row)
  }
  copyto.getRange(1,1,pasteValues.length,pasteValues[0].length).setValues(pasteValues);

}
```

I'm pretty sure I should maybe still be using array.splice() but haven't been successful trying to implement it achieve what i want, here's how the transposed sheet should look:

[image]

Info:

- Each group of addresses inside the "copyfrom" sheet would be separated by at least 1 blank line
- The length of an address group is not static, some can have 5 rows, others can have 8, but address groups are always separated by blank rows

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Don't have any code to share but here's an idea you can try to implement. Assuming that the 'Name' field/row is always present across all groups, maybe you can try partitioning your data based on that. So basically every time you hit a row with a 'Name' field you know you're starting a new group.

Comment: I think this might be done with Spreadsheet formulas more easily than appscript.  Can you paste a representative sample in this blank sheet that was created specifically for this question? 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AKjzcMJUkU8WTTOPgxhT--KeFhfD9VThxcqDvAZBGq8/edit

Comment: @MattKing I found the answer below already but yes if its possible to do the same thing **automatically** like how the script did then maybe it will help someone. Something to fire `=transpose(range)` for each datablock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to iterate all input values, and I can suggest the similar code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyfrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('copyfrom')
  var copyto = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('copyto')
  
  var values = copyfrom.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var pasteValues = [[]];  // keep result data here 

  values.forEach(function(v) {  // Iterate all input values
    // The last row to be filled in currently
    var row = pasteValues[pasteValues.length - 1];
    if (v[0]) {
      row.push(v[0]);
    } else if (row.length > 0) {
      while (row.length < 10) {
        row.push('');  // Adjust row length 
      }
      pasteValues.push([]);
    } 
  });
  if (pasteValues[pasteValues.length - 1].length == 0) pasteValues.pop();

  copyto.getRange(1, 1, pasteValues.length, pasteValues[0].length).setValues(pasteValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, but I think when it gets to the last row in the sheet it fails with the error "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 10"

So a failsafe for pasting the final row would top this script off, I have no idea if its really all the data but I did a browse and it seems to be, I checked out the last group in copy from and the last row in copy to and they seem to match

Comment: Right. We should check the last row length more carefully. If it is equal to 0, then the row should be removed from the final result. I have corrected the code correspondingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Assuming that every new row begins with `Name`, you can use this script to rearrange the column:

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyfrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('copyFrom');
  var copyto = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('copyTo');
  var lastRow = copyfrom.getLastRow();
  var values = copyfrom.getRange(1,1,lastRow).getValues().filter(Array);
  var pasteValues = [];
  var row = [];
  var maxLen = 1;

  // rearrange rows
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] == "Name" && i > 0) {
      pasteValues.push(row);
      row = [values[i]];
    }
    else if (values[i] != "") {
      row.push(values[i]);
      if (row.length > maxLen) {
        maxLen = row.length;
      }
    }
  }
  pasteValues.push(row);
  
  // append spaces to make the row lengths the same
  for (j = 0; j < pasteValues.length; j++) {
    while (pasteValues[j].length < maxLen) {
      pasteValues[j].push('');
    }
  }

  copyto.getRange(1,1,pasteValues.length,maxLen).setValues(pasteValues);
}
```

Sample I/O:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but going through the data to manually Add this might take just as much time as typing `=transpose(range)` inside an opposite cell and repeating that process. There are 8 sheets to be cleaned each with 3000+ rows so trying to avoid going through the sheet to add data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get the columns to line up in the output since you don't have any way to tell the difference between, for example, an "address 2" and a "City".

However, as far as merely grouping and transposing each address.  This one formula, in one cell, [in the tab here called MK.Help](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AKjzcMJUkU8WTTOPgxhT--KeFhfD9VThxcqDvAZBGq8/edit#gid=1208993731) will work from the data you provided.  It will work for as many contacts as you have.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({A:A,IFERROR(LOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A="")),0),COUNTIFS(IFERROR(LOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A="")),0),IFERROR(LOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER(ROW(A:A),A:A="")),0),A:A,"<>",ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A))},"select MAX(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col2 pivot Col3",0),"offset 1",0))
```